# Rails 4.2.10 Dirty changes triggers even that nested-fields not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

I've getting this problem just once after updating the record, after updated record if i try same things over again there is no problem

For example i have a prices table for my products, and it is nested in products

when i make changes for products table itself, my price nested field triggers changes also example below when i debug with binding.pry;

```
[1] pry(#<Price>)> changes
=> {"prices"=>[[#<BigDecimal:7fea13b5ddd0,'0.16E1',18(18)>], [#<BigDecimal:7fea13afc698,'0.16E1',18(18)>]],
 "updated_at"=>[Wed, 05 Sep 2018 16:14:07 BST +01:00, Thu, 27 Sep 2018 09:57:49 BST +01:00]}

[2] pry(#<Price>)> dd
NameError: undefined local variable or method `dd' for #<Price:0x00007fea13afe650>
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activemodel-4.2.10/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'

[3] pry(#<Price>)> changes
=> {"prices"=>[[#<BigDecimal:7fe9f5623748,'0.16E1',18(18)>], [#<BigDecimal:7fea13afc698,'0.16E1',18(18)>]],
 "occured_dates"=>[[Wed, 05 Sep 2018], [Wed, 05 Sep 2018]],
 "updated_at"=>[Wed, 05 Sep 2018 16:14:07 BST +01:00, Thu, 27 Sep 2018 09:57:49 BST +01:00]}
```

change triggers might be my codes but wierd thing when i send wrong method to active_model in binding.pry console it gives me more changed attributes after that even there is no action happend between.

**Edit:**

problem was cause by BigDecimal keep creating new BigDecimal on the progress

Comment: Seems like Bigdecimal triggers to changes

Comment: The second `changes` object includes references to `occured_dates` which weren't there the first time. In debugging your source code, I'd look at places which might touch that attribute and see how that might have been called. Is it possible there's an implementation that relies on `#method_missing`?